# Can I run Simulink on an Android device?

Tags: android, matlab, simulink

We are developing an Android application which needs to run a Simulink (Matlab) simulation.
Does anyone knows if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Using the add-on products MATLAB Coder and/or Simulink Coder, you can convert a subset of the MATLAB language, and many Simulink models into C-code that can be made suitable to run on Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can now run your Simulink models on Android devices using the Samsung Galaxy Android Support package.
Here is the link for the package:

http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/android-programming-simulink.html

As far as i know, you do not need MATLAB mobile/coder products to use the support package.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can only connect your android device with a MATLAB session running on a computer. Refering to [this page](http://freeapkforandroid.wordpress.com/tag/simulink/) it is possible to use SIMULINK as well. [Here](http://www.mathworks.de/videos/matlab-mobile-for-android-overview-72032.html) is a short introduction by MATHWORKS how it works.

Comment: The links provided are to MATLAB Mobile for Android. MATLAB Mobile is an app that allows your phone to connect to a copy of MATLAB running on your machine or in the cloud. It does not enable you to run MATLAB (or Simulink) directly on your phone.